# Search for a specific word when reading a --traceroute command in java code using bufferreader

Tags: java, process, nmap

I am trying to search the word `"hop"` from the traceroute output, but somehow its not displaying that line on console. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestExec {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String[] cmdarray = { "nmap", "--traceroute", "nmap.org" };
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          p.getInputStream()));
      String line = null;
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("hop")) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `exec("cmdarray");` should be `exec(cmdarray);`

Comment: sorry I posted wrong but executed with exec(cmdarray). still wont works.

Comment: You have missing semicolon after array initialisation. Also print stacktrace is useless. You could easily get rid of try-catch and just throws IOException - SAME EFFECT

Comment: @sam - you don't get anything printed out, but program is still running, right ?

Comment: did you try directly in command prompt, nmap --traceroute nmap.org, did you get any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. Are you running this in Linux? If you are, you have to run `nmap` as `root`. Are you doing so?
2. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to look for. In my run of `nmap --traceroute nmap.org`, there were no lines that contained the word `"hop"` in lowercase. So even if you are running this program as root, you probably aren't getting very much. [I'm fairly certain it doesn't print the word `"hop"` in lowercase on Windows, either.](http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html)

Comment: I will add:
- I managed to run this from command line (OSx), but I thing it differers from OS to OS. My was running till I haven't terminate it

Comment: Thank you so much It was my mistake I gave the search word "Hop".it should be "HOP" . It works now.

Comment: @sam if you feel my answer helped you, please click the checkmark next to the answer.